# Concatenate or insert a number into a QUERY() string in Google Sheets

Tags: google-sheets

I am trying to use `QUERY()` to call a column of data from one sheet to another based on the contents of other columns. The code below works just fine.

```
=query(Data!$A1:$Y15), "select Col7 where Col1 starts with """&E$2&""" ")
```

However, I want to copy this data and have `Col7` change to match the row of the cell that the formula is in `+ 1`. It should be something like this (the formula is in cell F6):

```
=query(Data!$A1:$Y15), "select Col"""Row(F6) + 1""" where Col1 starts with """&E$2&""" ")
```

How can I concatenate or insert a number into a query string? I do need to use query due to some other constraints I simplified out of this example.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just use `&` for concatenation, the way you did around `E$2`.

```
"select Col" & Row(F6) + 1 & " where Col1 starts with """ & E$2 & """ "
```

I would also use single quotes around the string from `E$2`, because they don't need to be escaped by doubling:

```
"select Col" & Row(F6) + 1 & " where Col1 starts with '" & E$2 & "'"
```

Also, `Row(F6)` could be simply `Row()` which returns the row of the current cell.